# How to shift columns in polars by a time interval (where another column is gives the timestamp)?

Tags: datetime, python-polars

In a polars dataframe it's very common to use the .shift method to compare successive rows - eg

```py
df.with_columns(difference_from_3_rows_ago = pl.col('myValue') - pl.col('myValue').shift(3))
```

However, when you have time indexed data it's not ideal to operate on it based on row numbers.

Is there anything that implements the following pseudo-code?

```py
(df
  .with_columns(
    difference_from_3d_ago = pl.col('myValue') - pl.col('myValue').shift('3d', by='myDateColumn'))
)
```

I was hoping there is a datetime-aware .shift method, else I'll be doing some self-joins or some checks to ensure the row offsets are appropriate

Comment: This would assume your data is sorted, right? It sounds like maybe you could use `.search_sorted()` + `.dt.offset_by()` - an example would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work although untested...

```
df.join(
    df.select(
        pl.col('myDateColumn').dt.offset_by('3d'),
        pl.col('myValue').alias('difference_from_3d_ago')
    ), on='myDateColumn'
).with_columns(
    difference_from_3d_ago = pl.col('myValue')-pl.col('difference_from_3d_ago')
)
```

It works by making a version of the df with the date column offset 3 days and an alias of the column to be differenced. That is joined to itself on the date column which then gives you the value offset by the 3 days. Lastly you take the difference of the original value and it's lagged version from the join.

Comment: Thank you - yes, I do something like this, but ideally I'd avoid a join for this. I'm looking into the `upsample` DataFrame method - maybe there is a solution there.

Comment: You can use upsample to make it so that you can be sure how many days back your shift would go but I'm not sure, if even a bit skeptical, that you'd realize better performance with that relative to a join. joins are very efficient.